# MongoDB Robo 3T add array (list) to index

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB and I would like to know how to add an index to a collection which is a version list with sub-indexes using Robo 3T?

I'll elaborate on my current collection index structure:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "Name" : "My name"
    "VersionList": 1
}
```

The required collection index structure should become as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "Name" : "My name"
    "VersionList": 
    [
        0: 
        {
            "Frequency" : 0,
            "Information" : "Revision information",
            "Trigger" : {},
            "D" : 
            {
                "DataType": "Actual value",
                "Unit": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I used tool Robo 3T to add the indexes. My problem is that I don't know how to add the sub-indexes of VersionList with Robo 3T and could not find clear examples how to do this. Could someone please show me how to do this?

Thanx in advance,

Bokki

Answer (score 0):

Dissapointing to not get any answers from the "mongo guru's", so I found out myself how to fix this by trying things out...

For other MongoDB newbies struggling with this issue:
It's as easy as: just insert documents to collection.

Steps in Robo 3T to add "sub-indexes" with arrays and so on:

1. RightClick on server connection -> Create Database
2. RightClick on Collections -> Create Collection...
3. RightClick on Indexes -> Add Indexes...
4. RightClick on your collection -> Insert Document...
5. In "Insert Document" window, add any valid JSON structure (this can be tested with the "Validate" button) and then press "Save".

Hope this helps someone!